# Dimensional reduction and Schwarzschild solution

Tags: general-relativity, specific-reference

It is well-known that, given a Killing vector $\xi_\mu$ for a metric, this can be dimensionally reduced. This is exactly the case of the Schwarzschild solution due to the rotational symmetry. This procedure is quite general and one can always reformulate a general 2d (or 3d) model, as the Jackiw-Teitelboim model, of general relativity and obtain solutions for the 4d case with the given symmetry properties. A reference about this is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204253). The effect, as always happens in dimensional reduction, is to introduce another field into the gravity action.

So far, I was not able to see the derivation of the reduced Schwarzschild metric from the dimensionally reduced Einstein equations. This is generally given for granted. So, I would appreciate to see such a derivation or to get some tutorial about this.

Comment: The dimensional reduction in this case is just plugging in Schwarzschild's ansatz for the metric.

Comment: @RonMaimon: The point here is that I have the dimensional reduced action (or equations if you want). I would like to see, from these equations, how to derive the Schwarzschild metric using Schwarzschild coordinates. It is always taken for granted as in the reference I cite. Even if it would be a homework, I would like to see the solution. The general solution of Jackiw-Teitelboim theory has not such a solution as far as I know. A reference would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimensionally reduced Einstein-Hilbert action of a spherically invariant metric is a special case of two-dimensional dilaton gravity. This type of theories was the subject of a quite extensive research at least in the past decade or so. It has applications in integrable systems, quantization of 1+1 gravity and it (what is relevant to this question) offers an alternative proof of the Birkhoff's theorem (: The Schwarzchild solution is the unique spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum Einstein equations). In many of these works the Schwarzchild solution was obtained as a byproduct as the solution of the 2-d field equations

Technically it is not very easy since it requires the solution of nonlinear partial differential field equations in 2D. In the following [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9811059) by Marco
Cavaglià the derivation is quite transparent, which can be summarized as follows:

Starting from the general spherically symmetric 3+1 metric:

$$ds^2 = \phi^{-\frac{1}{2}}g_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}+\phi d\Omega^2$$

(the indices run over a Lorentzian 2-space). After the substitution in the Einstein-Hilbert action and the integration of the angular coordinates, the following reduced 2d theory is obtained:

$S = \int d^2x \sqrt{-g}[\phi R^{(2)}(g) + V(\phi)]$, with ,

$$V(\phi)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt\phi}$$

The field equations:

$$ (\nabla_{(\mu}\nabla_{\nu)}- g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\sigma}\nabla^{\sigma})\phi + \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}V(\phi)=0$$

$$R+\frac{dV}{d\phi}=0$$

The nonlinear field equations can be solved by means of a Bäcklund transformation:

$$ \nabla_{\mu} \psi = \frac{\nabla_{\mu}\phi }{\nabla_{\sigma}\phi\nabla^{\sigma}\phi}$$

Leading to the following linear field equations

$$\nabla_{\sigma}\nabla^{\sigma}\psi = 0$$

and

$$\nabla_{\sigma} M = 0$$

with

$$M = N - \nabla_{\sigma}\phi\nabla^{\sigma}\phi$$

and

$$N = \int^{\phi}V(\phi\prime)d\phi\prime$$

The linear field equations can be solved in the conformal gauge:

$$ds^2 = \rho(u,v)dudv$$

as:

$$\psi = U(u) + V(v),$$ and $M=const.$

The solution for the metric is obtained from the Bäcklund transformation equation:

$$\rho^2 = \partial_u\phi \partial_v\phi\partial_u\psi \partial_v\psi ,$$ or

$$\rho= (N(\phi)-M)\partial_u\psi \partial_v\psi ,$$

and

$$\frac{d\psi}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{N-M}$$

By performing a coordinate transformation to the independent variables $U$ and $V$ instead of $u$ and $v$ respectively. We obtain:

$$\rho= N(\phi(U+V))-M)$$

Again changing the coordinates to T=U-V and $\phi(U+V)$, we  obtain:

$$ds^2 = (N-M)dT^2+(N-M)^{-1}d\phi^2$$

which is the Schwarzchild solution for $N=\sqrt\phi$.

Please observe that the metric was not assumed to be stationary, thus this derivation consists of a proof of Birkhoff's theorem.